# Database select on Php $db->select

Tags: php, database, select

28517 This is my folder id. **how can i put 2 or more different folder id there?**

```
$where_text = "`indir`= '28517'";

$data = $db->select("SELECT * 
                    FROM `". MAI_PREFIX ."files` 
                    WHERE $where_text 
                    ORDER BY `".$set->plugins["top_sort"]."` ".$set->plugins["top_sort_type"]." 
                    LIMIT 0,".$set->plugins["top_number"]);
```

Comment: Try this `$where_text = "`indir`= '28517' AND `indir`= '28518' AND `indir`= '28518'";`

Comment: @Mr.Developer You might want to delete this comment as the use of `AND` would not achieve the required result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `IN()` clause like this

```
$where_text = "`indir` IN('28517', '28518', '28519')";
```

Now its just a case of working out how to build this statement from your existing data, which unfortunately you dont tell us about

Answer (score 4):

[IN()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) operator can help for this task.

```
$where_text = "`indir` IN('28517','28518','28519')";
```

**Edited**

After @RiggsFolly comment  I have correct my mistake. Thank you @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 3):

You could use `WHERE ... IN (.., ..)` :

```
$where_text = "`indir` in ('28517','28518')";
```